# Improve performances in loading data in a MAUI page

Tags: c#, maui

I'm creating an app with MAUI and NET7. How you can see in the following record, the application is working but when I open a page with data, the render is quite slow.

[image]

In the *ViewModel* I have my function to read the data

```
[ObservableProperty] private List<Dictionary> _dictionaries;

public async Task Init()
{
    IsRefreshing = true;

    await ReadDb();

    IsRefreshing = false;
}

public async Task ReadDb()
{
    // retrieve data from the database
    Dictionaries = await database.GetDictionaries();
}
```

then in the page

```
public partial class DictionaryList : ContentPage
{
    DictionaryListViewModel vm;

    public DictionaryList(DictionaryListViewModel model)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        vm = model;
        BindingContext = vm;
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        // show a loading popup
        var popup = new LoadingPopup();
        this.ShowPopup(popup);

        await vm.Init();
        popup.Close();
    }
}
```

I defined the *ListView* like that

```
<ListView x:Name="listDictionaries" ItemsSource="{Binding Dictionaries}" 
            ItemSelected="listDictionaries_ItemSelected"
            SelectionMode="Single" HasUnevenRows="True" 
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" 
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
    <ListView.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger TargetType="ListView">
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding IsEmpty}" Value="True" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
        </MultiTrigger>
    </ListView.Triggers>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="dt:Dictionary">
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="10" 
                      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <!-- All the XAML -->
                </Grid>
                <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <MenuItem Text="{lang:Translate Edit}"
                        Clicked="OnEdit"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                </ViewCell.ContextActions>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

For example, the loading popup is shown for a few seconds but when it disappears, the *ListView* or *CollectionView* is not populated: the app takes a while to display the data.

What is the best practice or the efficient way to load the data but also to have a nice user experience?

Comment: A good place to start is to measure so you are actually sure you know what is taking time. Then try to optimize it if you can (only fetch data you need, use indices etc). Actual rendering performance is not the first thing I would expect to be slow for a fairly simple application.

Comment: What does `ReadDb()` do apart from reading data from a database (as the name suggests)? Is that where the data gets added to the `Dictionaries` observable property? What type does `Dictionaries` have and how do you access it? Also note that ListView has inferior performance compared to CollectionView. You may want to consider changing the ListView to CollectionView, if possible.

Comment: Compiled bindings is usually a good start

Comment: @Julian I updated the code. The data are coming from a SQLite database on the device. I tried to use the `CollectionView` but the context menu is quite ugly.

Comment: You're binding to `Dictionaries` but your code shows a property called `Words` - how are they related?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the easiest way to improve performance be it in Maui or XF is to use Compiled Bindings on your pages,

Based on the type of your data, Compiling a binding expression generates compiled code that typically resolves a binding 8-20 times quicker than using a classic binding.

So your View will have the Datatype of your ViewModel and your ListView and CollectionView's template will have the Model's template

Assuming, ListViewPage is your Page, ListViewModel is your ViewModel and ListModel is your Model you can do the following:

```
<ListViewPage
   .
   .
   .
   xmlns:models="**ModelNamespace**"
   xmlns:viewModels="**ViewModelNamespace**"
   x:DataType="viewModels:ListViewModel">
   
   <ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:ListModel">
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
 </ListViewPage>
```

You can also check this blog of mine which is for Xamarin Forms but has some things that could apply to Maui, https://medium.com/cometheartbeat/techniques-for-improving-performance-in-a-xamarin-forms-application-b439f2f04156

I do plan on writing a new one for Maui this weekend so I will update that here as well.

I also recommend using something like a SkeletonEffect https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyEffects which can make your app look smoother while loading data.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm already using the `x:DataType`. I'll read your post. Do you plan to extend the _FreakyEffects_ also for macCatalyst and Windows?

Comment: Maybe in the future as of right now I am focusing the mobile to be honest